# Classes and methods

Tags: c#

I am working on a project with classes and override methods in C#. I am still new to it and learning. I have two classes. One is called `CalculateValues`. That one is where you can add two numbers. Then on my next class, it is multiplying. This might sound goofy, but I am trying to figure the code up where on the add button a person can click on it to add the two numbers and output the result in a `MessageBox`. This is the code I have for my add class:

```
class CalculateValues
{
    private int _num1;
    private int _num2;

    public int Add(int _num1, int _num2)
    {
        return _num1 + _num2;
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        return _num1 + _num2;
    } 
}
```

Now the code I am thinking about goes like this

```
int total = myAdd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
```

But its not working. I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong or I must be wording it wrong.

This is what I am trying to do so there aint no mix up create a class called calculateValues.cs in that create 2 private variables num1 and num2. Then create a public properties corresponding to num1 and num2. Then create a public overridable method called calculate that add these two variables together and return the result.

Next i create a class called multiplyvalues.cs. In this class i am trying to override the calculate method so that it multiplies the number instead of adding them. Next I have to add a code behind each button that will add and multiply  numbers and output it in a messagebox.

Comment: "But its not working." - that's never enough of a description of the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: Let me guess, it's not compiling?

Comment: Firstly, what's not working? Secondly, your `Calculate()` method is declared as an overriding method, so where's your base class containing it's counterpart?

Comment: You'll get an exception from int.Parse if the text in your textboxes is not a number (can't be parsed as an integer). Use int.TryParse instead and check the return value.

Comment: Judging by your post you made earlier today, I'm going to assume it's definitely not override you're after here. It's used for a slightly more advanced OOP principle called polymorphism. I've got a feeling there'll be a simple solution to this - you just need to ask the right question, which should explain what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you're getting an error along the lines of "The method you're trying to override doesn't exist in the base class."

Your `CalculateValues` method derives directly from `System.Object`, which doesn't have a virtual or abstract `Calculate` method, so there's nothing to override. It's not clear what you're *trying* to achieve using `override`, but there's no polymorphism here... did you mean to specify a base class for `CalculateValues`?

Answer (score 1):

Override doesn't override methods within a class (it seems like you are trying that with your `Add(...)` and `Calculate()` methods ). It is to override methods from a base class, and in your case, that is the `System.Object`, which wouldn't have that method and cause compilation error.

If you are looking for a static method for `Add`, then you can do so and remove the `override` in `Calculate()` and assign the `num1` and `num2` values in a constructor / setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can *try* tp do something like this:

```
public abstract class IntCalculator
{
   protected List<int> values = new List<int>();
   public void AddValue(int value) { values.Add(value); }
   public abstract int Calculate(); 

}

public class Adder : IntCalculator
{
   public override int Calculate()
   {
        return  values.Sum(x=>x);
   }
}


public class Multiplier : IntCalculator
{
   public override int Calculate()
   {
        return  //multiply all values;
   }
}
```

Something like this. This is just an idea to explore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create different calculators, you could derive them from an abstract base class

```
abstract class Calculator
{
    protected int _num1;
    protected int _num2;

    public Calculator(int num1, int num2)
    {
        _num1 = num1;
        _num2 = num2;
    }

    public abstract int Calculate();
}
```

In the derived classes you will have to implement the abstract method `Calculate`

```
class AddingCalculator : Calculator
{
    public AddingCalculator(int num1, int num2)
        : base(num1, num2)
    {
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        return _num1 + _num2;
    }
}

class SubtractingCalculator : Calculator
{
    public SubtractingCalculator(int num1, int num2)
        : base(num1, num2)
    {
    }

    public override int Calculate()
    {
        return _num1 - _num2;
    }
}
```

You can use these calculators like this

```
Calculator calculator;

calculator = new AddingCalculator(5, 7);
Console.WriteLine(calculator.Calculate());

calculator = new SubtractingCalculator(5, 7);
Console.WriteLine(calculator.Calculate());
```

---

Note: An abstract class cannot be instantiated, i.e. you cannot write

```
var calculator = new Calculator(); // Not allowed!
```

---

The code ...

```
: base(num1, num2)
```

... in the constructors of the derived classes calls the constructor of the base class.